# 3D-PDF with U3D-File - how to create 3Dviews with .vws?

Tags: media9

Everything is still working - the 3D-Animation of a 3D-Part in my PDF and other options like the `3Dmenu` or the `toolbar`.

But now I want to add some Mediabuttons with `\mediabutton[3Dgotoview=...]`. For this opportunity I need a working Views-File with informations about the views. The content of my views-file is just easy to get with the JavaScriptConsole. But how can I create such a file? Just for contents like:

```
VIEW=First View
  COO=-43.4 -1603.9 2199.1
  C2C=0.03 -0.5 -0.8
  ROO=2274.1
  LIGHTS=CAD
END
```

Yours sincerely and thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You fill the JavaScript console with as many `VIEW` sections as you want, by manipulating the  model to your liking and then selecting '*Get Current View*' from the context menu. This requires `\includemedia` option **`3Dmenu`**.

Copy the console content and paste it into a text file, say `myviews.vws`, opened in a text editor of your liking. Edit the file, giving meaningful names to the generated views, e. g. `VIEW=First View` etc.

Now edit your `*.tex` file to make use of `myviews.vws` and to insert media buttons:

```
\includemedia[
  label=my3dobject,
  3Dviews=myviews.vws,
  width=4cm,height=4cm,
  3Dmenu,
  ...
]{click!}{something.u3d}\\
\mediabutton[3Dgotoview=my3dobject:(First View)]{\fbox{First View}}
\mediabutton[...]{...}
```

Finally, when you are done, option `3Dmenu` can be removed.

See, e. g. the example in Fig. 7 of the `media9` documentation.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your quick help Alex. I copied the results from the JavaScript console ('Get Current View') into a .txt-File and saved it under the name 'myviews.vws'. Now if I run the Tex-File I got the Message '!media9 error: "file not found" - File: 'myviews.vws' not found.' ... The file is just in the same folder as the *.tex-file. So what for a problem could it be?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Confetti_Cannon: Weird. Sure you made no typo while naming the views file (CaSe mAtTeRs!)?

Comment: Yea, now I tried it with a smaller example, but still the same problem - the 'views.vws not found'. This File is still a Text-File and saved just with the text wrote above ("VIEW=..... [...] END") and saved in the folder of the .tex-/u3d-folder, right?

Comment: If it is in the same folder as your `*tex` and your `*u3d` it should be ok. Are you running Windows? Be sure, while renaming, Windows doesn't silently append `.txt` to the file name, creating a file `myviews.vws.txt`. BTW, it is not mandatory for views files to end in `.vws`, `myviews.txt` will do as well. Of course, you must say `3Dviews=myviews.txt` then.

Comment: Just a simple solution for a subjective big problem... Yeah, plus .txt it works! Really great, thanks a lot, AlexG!